# Message box on selected index change

Tags: messagebox

I am trying this JavaScript code to give user a message when selected item from a drop down list contains "Ultra Low" but is not working. Can someone please help?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("ddGlass");
    dropdown.onchange = function (event) {
        if (dropdown.str.indexOf("Ultra Low") > -1) {
            alert("Glass Option is for Yuma Only")
        }
    }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get `dropdown.str`? It should be `dropdown.value`.

Comment: Post the rest of the html in your question or a fiddle or code pen, something else must be wrong

Comment: I replaced the entire thing with below code and it works now. Thanks everyone.             ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Glass Option is for Yuma Only');", true);